# Connecting to device on nested router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've got an Eero mesh Wifi setup in my home, with one of the satellite nodes on my boat (about 50' behind the house). Also on the boat I've got a TP-Link WiFi router that is plugged into the satellite node. The reason for this is when the boat is away from the house I don't want connected devices freaking out trying to connect to the base station, etc.

Here's my issue though: I've got one particular device on the boat network that broadcasts monitoring data (NMEA 2000) on port 2000, via both TCP and UDP. I want to connect from my home network to that device to receive that data. I think the answer is some sort of NAT or something but I'm not sure.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes you need to use the TPlink management console to port forward TCP\UDP 2000 to the GPS device. then you should be able to consume the service provided on the GPS device from inside the house. you may want to check here to see if they have instructions for your model or family of devices. https://portforward.com/ Also most good routers will automatically open the firewall for port-forward rules, but in case it doesn't make sure that the inbound connection is allowed by the router firewall.